# SharePoint List view which is filtered based on the Query String shows no items when pagination is used

Tags: list-view, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have created one view of a custom list. The item limit of this view is 5. It is filtered based on the value as shown in below image:

[image]

I have added a web part of this view in a page and bound it with Parameter Binding alike below:

```
<ParameterBinding Name="Team" Location="QueryString{Team}" DefaultValue="" />
```

Now when I refresh the page for the first time, the view is populated with the values which are linked to the Parameter i.e. 'Team'.

But when I click on pagination to view more items of this view, I am getting below message:

> There are no items to show in this view of the "ABC" list.

There are more than 5 items related to 'Team' then also the above message is displayed.

Please help why SharePoint shows this behaviour instead of having items to display in this view.

Comment: Please verify in the web part property : "server rendering" is unchecked

Comment: It is unchecked. When I check it, the page's behaviour is as expected but it is going for a server call. Is there any way instead of a server call that it is managed at client side and pagination works as expected?